# Apache Web Server Redirect Post Request

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I configured apache on 4 ports (with virtual hosts as some ports used HTTPS) and the aim is to redirect post requests to different servlets running in a TOMCAT instance on some other machine. The calls are made from a `httpclient` (java client) . When I run the client it throws the error 301 Error: Moved Permanently. Need hints/tips/help on how to solve the this problem.

It would be nice if someone can give me a example. My virtual host (with the re-direction) 
looks like something like this

```
<VirtualHost _default_:3334>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/$ https://192.168.100.23:38443/Lang/Englangservices/Alapbhet_service
<\VirtualHost>
```

---

I am now able to get mod proxy working with mod rewrite and now I dont get the 302 error, but as it always happens to a newbie there is this another problem.

HTTP POST requests are not working. When I issue the post request, the proxy fails as it goes on to look for index.htm.

My httpd.conf snippet

```
<VirtualHost *:3331>
  ServerName localhost:3331
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.100.23:38443/Lang/Englangservices/Alapbhet_service
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.100.23:38443/Lang/Englangservices/Alapbhet_service
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/$ http://localhost:3331/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It would be nice if someone can give me a example. My virtual host (with the re-direction) looks  like something like this

<VirtualHost _default_:3334>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^/$  https://192.168.100.23:38443/Lang/Englangservices/Alapbhet_service
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved this using JK and mod rewrite. The problem was with two way SSL and I configured the ports to run in conjunction with 443 (SSL) port.

i.e.

Note: if one intends to rewrite URL's in the virtual hosts then JK mount has to be reloaded for each virtual host.

My URL rewrites look like this

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 4342
RewriteRule ^/$ /Lang/Englangservices/Alapbhet_service  [L,PT]

Thanks everyone one for their inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Another option additional to the already given mod _ proxy is mod _ jk. (sorry for the spaces, otherwise formatting is messed up)

Both are apache extensions that allow apache to consume the request, transparently forward it to tomcat, wait for the response and then send the result back.

IMHO mod_jk has a few advantages

- Tomcat automagically gets the served hostname, protocol and port (with mod_proxy you have to configure the fact that it's proxied in the Connector, see the options [proxyName and proxyPort](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html)
- mod_jk provides loadbalancing - should you need this
- apache speaks to tomcat in a protocol designed for this task (ajp13). With mod_proxy they talk http, which has a slightly higher overhead (Disclosure: I've never measured it myself, just parrotting it)

What you use in the end is completely your choice - it's not *that* much a difference between both options. (Someone correct me if it is)

Configuration is as follows (untested pseudocode. *Do* read the docs, please understand what you do...)

```
# somewhere in httpd.conf, above the virtual hosts
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
JkLogFile     /var/log/apache/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    error

# your existing part with virtual hosts
<VirtualHost ...>
   ....
   JkMount /Lang/* tomcat1
   JkMount /Lang   tomcat1  # if you need the directory itself also to be forwarded
   ....
</VirtualHost>

# the workers.properties file described above
# 'tomcat1' is the reference used above as argument to JkMount
workers.list=tomcat1
worker.tomcat1.port=8009
worker.tomcat1.host=localhost
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.lbfactor=1
```

Answer (score 2):

A 301 sounds like the appropriate response if you really want to redirect, but maybe you really wanted to proxy the requests so that the client was unaware of the redirect? In this case, take a look at using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) as a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Your httpclient in java needs to properly handle 301 answers.  If it does not, it is broken.  If you don't want or can't, then using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)/[mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) as indicated by Paul to "transparently" redirect is the way to go. See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/)